# What is a good place to initialize API clients in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

To give an example, these two gems https://github.com/philnash/bitly and https://github.com/nfo/gmail_xoauth require something like

```
client = Bitly.client
```

And

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, usessl = true, certs = nil, verify = false)
```

Am I suppose to initialize these clients every time I use them? Eg in every function I need to use methods from those clients?

EDIT: still not sure how to go about initizalizing a library like this

```
require 'mixpanel-ruby'
tracker = Mixpanel::Tracker.new(PROJECT_TOKEN)
tracker.track(user_id, 'Sent Message')
```

Answer (score 2):

create ocnfig/initializers/bitly.rb

```
config.bitly_client = Bitly.client
```

Comment: I did something like config.linkedin_client = LinkedIn::Client.new inside a linkedin.rb and rails didn't like it

Comment: can you give me a bit more explanation?

Answer (score 1):

You can also write this in any of the Environment files under config/environments/ also for environment specific solution or even in config/environment.rb also where it applies to all environments as an option to config/initializers/any_file_name.rb.

Make sure the Class name must be appropriate in case of config/initializers/any_file_name.rb

Comment: What do you mean by the Class name must be appropriate?

Comment: In case you are redefining the Method written in API, Create a Module for Example for Paperclip - it is a Gem used for File Upload
`module Paperclip`
  `class AssetUrlGenerator < UrlGenerator`
   _some code_
  `end`
`end`

If you want to Define/Set any Values
`Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = "/attachments/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:fingerprint.:extension"`

Answer (score 0):

If the client just needs configuration for your own tokens and such.
I would setup a client in a app/config/initializers/goodreads.rb
all files in the initialize folder will get loaded into your environment.

If you are setting up a unique client per a User's own token you may want to make a helper method in a concern.

once you create your client save it to a variable and use throughout your application as needed.